# what does 線 mean here?

Tags: words, usage

The context here is that an elevator fell and someone died in the fall

> ワイヤを止めてる金具が外れて落下という線には間違いないんだけどね

I understand the sentence but i can't wrap my head around 線's meaning here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 線 refers to a possible way of thinking, a possible solution (among others), an approach, etc. This is often used in detective stories.

> - 物事を行う道筋・方針。「その線で交渉しよう」 ([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/125520/meaning/m0u/))
> - 物事を行う上での（漠然とした）方針や道筋。「その線で考えてみよう」(明鏡国語辞典 第二版)
> - 8. line (of action); position; approach; policy; principle ([jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%B7%9A))

Comment: It makes sense now, Thank you! and this sentence is actually from a detective story